# flatMap is not working in Angular2

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

Hello guys i just created a simple ajax call in  which the response of first ajax call is used in second ajax call so i used flatmap in angular 2 to run first ajax call and use its response in second ajax call here is the code but only the first ajax call is working properly it seems like the code after .flatmap isnt running. please help me to solve this issue.

```js
createPerson(personClass: User, addressClass: Address): Rx.Observable <string> {
  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  headers.append("Cache-Control", "no-store");
  headers.append("If-Modified-Since", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
  var myObj = {
    "firstName": personClass.firstname,
    "age": personClass.age,
    "lastName": personClass.lastname,
    "dateOfBirth": "null"
  };

  return this.http.post(`${webServiceEndpoint}/person`, JSON.stringify(myObj), {
      headers: headers
    }).map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .flatMap(data => {
      let body = data.json();
      console.log(body);
      var myObj2 = {
        "personId": body,
        "address1": addressClass.streetname,
        "city": addressClass.city,
        "zipCode": addressClass.zipcode
      };

      return this.http.post(`${webServiceEndpoint}/address`, JSON.stringify(myObj2), {
        headers: headers
      }).map((res1: Response) => res1.json())
    })
}
```

Comment: any errors in your browsers developer tools console? what is `flatMap` anyway? and does `this.http.post` return an object with a `.map` method? that all sounds a bit funky to me

Comment: perhaps this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698649/angular-2-combine-three-http-calls-with-flatmap-rxjs may shed some light? I don't know

Comment: @JaromandaX no errors in console. to my knowledge Flatmap is used to chain HTTP requests. both post methods runs good individually but i want the response of first request to be used in second request.

Comment: Are there any errors in your error callback of your subscribe?

Comment: @LLai the console didnt show any error.

Comment: even in the `createPerson().subscribe(res => {}, err => { console.log(err)});`?

Answer (score 0):

As `data` is not a `Response` object this may be failing:

```
let body = data.json();
```

Comment: here i feel data is the response of first http request.  return this.http.post(`${webServiceEndpoint}/person`, JSON.stringify(myObj), {
            headers: headers
        }).map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .flatMap(data => {
         let body = data.json();
          console.log(body);

Comment: @what will be in data if it is not response object I'm new to angular any help is appreciated

Comment: `data` should be the returned value from previous map operator - `res.json()`. You can `console.log` and find out.

Comment: what ever console logged after .flatMap doesnt displays anything

Comment: Are you subscribing the observable returned from `createPerson` anywhere? Subscribing is required to make the observable emit anything.

Comment: when i try to subscribe i get this error  Argument of type '(data: any) => Subscription' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: any, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.
    Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'ArrayLike<{}>'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'Subscription'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using RxJS at the wrong way (you don't think reactive) (if you can use the newest version of angular):

**Example (very clean way to do this and you can test the code very easy):**

```
createPerson(personClass: User, addressClass: Address): Observable<Address> {
  /* Angular 5 you can do this into the HttpClient Interceptor */
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  headers.append("Cache-Control", "no-store");
  headers.append("If-Modified-Since", "Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");

  return this.createPerson(person)
    .switchMap((person: Person) => this.http.post<Person>(`${webServiceEndpoint}/person`, { person , headers})
    .switchMap((person: Person) => createAddress(person, address))
    .switchMap((person: Person) => this.http.post(`${webServiceEndpoint}/address`, person, {
        headers: headers
      }));
}

createAddress(person: Person, address: Address): Observable<Address> {
   return Observable.of({
     "personId": person.id,
     "address1": addressClass.streetname,
     "city": addressClass.city,
     "zipCode": addressClass.zipcode
   });
}

createPerson(person: Person): Observable<Person> {
  return Observable.of(<Person>{
    "firstName": personClass.firstname,
    "age": personClass.age,
    "lastName": personClass.lastname,
    "dateOfBirth": "null"
  });
}
```