# Ignore intermediate emissions of canceled Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

Users can fire off a search where I chain a variable number of HTTP requests using this approach: [Angular 2 combine three http calls with flatMap? RxJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698649/angular-2-combine-three-http-calls-with-flatmap-rxjs).

That's all fine and dandy, but I want to cancel the old search if it's still running when they fire off a new one. Something like this:

- User starts Search A

  - Search A part 1 starts
  - Search A part 1 ends
  - Search A part 2 starts
- User starts Search B

  - Search B part 1 starts
  - Search B part 1 ends
  - Search B completes
- User sees results for B (B part 1)

The closest I can find is [switchAll](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchAll) which does discard/cancel A part 2, but I'm getting A part 1 mixed into the results. Note: Only the last finished part is included, so if the user starts a new search during part `n`, then only `n - 1` is included (for `n > 1`) and `n - 2` and prior are discarded.

So my questions:

- **Why are the intermediate results running together?**
- **How do I achieve the effect I want?**

  - **Can I discard the previous search's intermediate results?**
  - **Can I treat the searches as singular emissions?**

The code I've got is a bit messy, but here's a rough, simplified outline:

```
// User fires this event.
startSearch() {
    this.searchSubject(getUsersCriteria());
}

ngOnInit() {
    // The event is transformed into a search request.
    this.searchSubject
        .asObservable()
        .pipe(
            map((criteria) => search(criteria)),
            switchAll(), // FIXME Not sufficient.
            tap((results) => this.setResults(results))
        )
        .subscribe();
}

/**
 * Execute the search and return the results.
 **/
search(criteria): Observable<Result[]> {
    return this.http.get('https://proprietary.com/endpoint', criteria)
        .pipe(flatMap((results) => {
            // Process results. Conditionally continue.
            if (done()) return of(results);
            else return search(criteria.nextCriteria())
                .pipe(map((moreResults) => [...results, ...moreResults]));
        });
}
```

*Note: Presently using RxJS 6.*

Comment: So you want to fresh start a search everytime and discard all the previous recursive chained result as well as only care about the combined result from the chain?

Comment: @FanCheung Yes, I believe you understand correctly.

Comment: but i can't see where you save the result from the previous results? could you provide more code to demonstrate how the result is being added up.

Comment: @FanCheung I've updated the question. Let me know if you think it needs more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An overzealous HTTP interceptor was returning results for the first (cancelled) search as well as (erroneously) the second search.

Double check HTTP interceptors.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works, but you can try pass in extra param as a start value for your result set. Everything when `searchSubject` fire ,new empty result set [] will be passed into the recursive chain.

```
ngOnInit() {
    // The event is transformed into a search request.
    this.searchSubject
        .asObservable()
        .pipe(
            switchMap((criteria) => search(criteria,[])),
            tap((results) => this.setResults(results))
        )
        .subscribe();
}


/**
 * Execute the search and return the results.
 **/
search(criteria,resultSet): Observable<Result[]> {
    return this.http.get('https://proprietary.com/endpoint', criteria)
        .pipe(flatMap((results) => {
            // Process results. Conditionally continue.
            if (done()) return of(resultSet);                
            return search(criteria.nextCriteria(),resultSet.concat(results))   
        });
}
```