# Is it possible to make multiple HTTP calls as a transaction

Tags: angular

I have a situation where I need to perform multiple HTTP calls to different endpoints but I need these calls to be performed together i.e if one fails the other should fail too or rollback. Is that possible using RxJS?

Comment: Define rollback. You could wrap several fetch calls in a Promise.all and know if they all failed/succeeded, but it isn't a transaction, its still multiple requests.

Comment: No, not without incorporating some sort of transaction system into the design of all the services you are calling. One approach that is fairly common these days to get something similar to what you want is the two-stage commit, but that's still not exactly comparable with the kind of transaction you'd have in an ACID database.

Comment: This is not a question you can ask us about. You need to ask the developers/maintainers of the endpoints weather they have a rollback feature.

Answer (score 1):

- Parallel: you can use [forkJoin()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin). Similar to Promise.all(), in case any one fails, all subscription will fail.
- Nested way: in case you http call depends to from a previus one, you can use [flatmap()](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to execute them one by one in order. By this way you will subscribe to every http call untill one of them fails because it calls the next one into subscribe() method. ([how to use flatmap/mergemap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698649/angular-2-combine-three-http-calls-with-flatmap-rxjs)).

Comment: Neither of these methods prevent the server from executing and committing one action and then failing and throwing a HTTP 500 error on the next one, though.